# How to import com.android.keyguard.KeyguardPatternView in my android project?

Tags: java, android

I need to use some functionality of this class in my android project for xposed module. I am unable to do so. Can anybody suggest how can I make this class com.android.keyguard.KeyguardPatternView visible to my project. Do I need to include any jar file. If so where can I find that jar file.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: You're supposed to use the XposedHelpers class to call methods in system classes

Answer (score 0):

try this one for your Refernce.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard/KeyguardServiceDelegate.java
[KeyGuard lock using Service Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274357/keyguard-lock-using-service-android)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a042ac90640c0c3fd3c5349083b86bbfd6319b64/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard/KeyguardPatternView.java
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1962e26/packages/Keyguard/src/com/android/keyguard/KeyguardViewMediator.java
https://gitorious.org/replicant/frameworks_base/source/2d6c9bb1b41a22a6e5e0f01be1c9b8931b55a71a:policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/keyguard/KeyguardViewManager.java

Comment: I can see those libraries, but when it comes to my android app I am unable to import those functions. I guess I must add some jar file in order to get those functions. Can you tell me which jar file I should add for getting lockscreen related functions and where to download the same.

Comment: Refer this links..http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=40413318  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the help. I could find the sources of KeyguardPatternView in android os sources. But I want to use that functionality in my android app. I tried downloading the jar file you mentioned in that xda thread but that jar file(android.policy.jar) but it only contains classes.jar. I am unable to see any methods in it.

Also let me know if it is the right way to hook a method in android.